# JS-Error: function is not known ("is not a function")

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Other people had this problem also, but I was not able to transfer the answers to my problem. So I just ask :-)*

I got this code, using a star-rating-plugin ("[rateit](http://rateit.codeplex.com)"):

```
<div class="rateit"></div>
```

Now I want to call a function after clicking on the div. When I just use

```
$(document).on('rated', '.rateit', function() { alert("aha"); });
```

this works, I get the alert. But when I call a function of the rateit-plugin with

```
$(document).on('rated', '.rateit', function() { ratingHelper.submit($(this).rateit('value'));
 });
```

I get the error ".rateit is not a function". I get the same error when using

```
$('.rateit').bind('rated', function() { ratingHelper.submit($(this).rateit('value')); });
```

The function to call looks like

```
var ratingHelper = function(){
};

ratingHelper.prototype = {      
    submit: function(v){
    ...
```

Well I am new to JS/jQuery and totally helpless. I would appreciate any help very much. Thanks in advance!

EDIT
Oh man ... I had the jquery.js imported TWICE :-( sorry for bothering you and thanks for your help!!

Comment: Well, do you include a jQuery plugin called `rateit`? Because that's what you're trying to call with `$(this).rateit()`

Comment: @Johan - Well if he did not then the event won't even be triggered at all.

Comment: According to the documentation it should work.

Comment: `$(document).on('rated', '.rateit', function() { alert($(this).rateit('value'));
 });` works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('event', 'element', callback);
```

event: name of event run 
element: elements of trigger 
callback: function run after trigger

In your case -> '.rateid' is class name in DOM, and in this - 
`$('.rateit').bind('rated', function() {});` you not pointing at the item